# Including a variable in a tkMessageBox.showinfo?

Tags: python, variables, tkinter

Im trying to include the "mye" variable in this message box in tkinter but its not working, i keep getting TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'type' and 'NoneType'. Can someone help me out please?

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import messagebox as tkMessageBox


mgui=Tk()

def confirm():
      tkMessageBox.showinfo("Info","A confirmation has been sent to" + str(mye))

email=StringVar()
e=str(email.get())

label4=Label(mgui,text="Please enter your email address", fg="black").grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=W)
button3=Button(mgui,text="Confirm",command=confirm).grid(row=1,column=1)

mye=Entry(mgui,textvariable=email).grid(row=6,column=1)

mgui.mainloop()
```

Comment: if you change to : `("Info","A confirmation has been sent to" + str(mye))` does it work?

Comment: the error doesn't come up, but instead of the variable being displayed in the box the word "None" is displayed.

Comment: That would indicate that the value of your variable is in fact none. As a test assign it some string value in the first line of the confirm function like 'hello world' and see if that value shows up. If so, your variable is not being assigned correctly

Comment: ive tried everything but now im getting "a confirmation has been sent to entry 3"?

Comment: If you can post a complete code snippet that captures your problem, it would make it easier to advise.  What you've got isn't really a complete example, otherwise known as an mcve: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Ive edited the post and entered the code snippet. Thank you for your help by the way :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create the `Entry` first, then grid it on another line. Creating and gridding it on the same line will always return `None` because you are assigning the output of the `grid` function to your variable when what you want is to assign the object created instead with the instantiation of `Entry`. This works:

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import messagebox as tkMessageBox


mgui=Tk()

def confirm():
      tkMessageBox.showinfo("Info","A confirmation has been sent to " + mye.get())
      #mye.get() returns contents of mye

email=StringVar()
e=str(email.get())

label4=Label(mgui,text="Please enter your email address", fg="black").grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=W)
button3=Button(mgui,text="Confirm",command=confirm).grid(row=1,column=1)

mye=Entry(mgui,textvariable=email)
mye.grid(row=6,column=1) #Grid the entry on another line

mgui.mainloop()
```